# Assigning matrix elements by indices collected in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, matrix, indices

I am trying to construct an affiliation matrix for a social network. I have a pd dataframe where column `i` is the i index of an element and column `j` is the j index of an element. Column `v` is the value of weight between two nodes.

I made up the following table for demonstration. I'll just call it `df`

| i | j | v |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

My idea was to first construct a matrix

```
A_matrix = np.zeros((i_num, j_num))
```

Then I use the apply function

```
df.apply(set_to_matrix)
```

where

```
def set_to_matrix(row):
    A_matrix[row.i, row.j] = row.v
```

My question is, Is it possible to get a better performance?

I have i_num = 100000 and j_num = 1000; with the code above it took me 1 minute 53 sec.

I tried using the `swifter` package to speed up the apply function, but it turns out to be 2 minutes 23 sec, which is longer.

If possible, also let me know why mine is slower and how other approach can potentially speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `apply`, you can use the `i` and `j` columns to index inside the `A_matrix` then assign the values from `v` column to the corresponding index positions:

```
A_matrix = np.zeros((i_num, j_num)) 
A_matrix[df.i, df.j] = df.v
```

Comment: This solution is neet and fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working for me & I didn't spend time to debug it. The following code will give you the matrix you require pretty quickly. The only issue is the duplicate rows (`1 & 2`) and columns (`1& 3`) will be combined together (& to me it makes sense!).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'i': [1,2,5,2,1,3],
                    'j': [3,4,3,1,2,1],
                    'v': [0,2,0,2,0.5,1]})

df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='v',index='i', columns='j', aggfunc=np.mean).reset_index().fillna(0)
```

Final network matrix:

```
print(df1.to_numpy())
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to give me the correct value on my data. Still appreciate the idea, I think using a pivot table is some cool idea. Maybe some adjustment might get the job done I guess.